# Dynamically creating hidden form fields for various models (MVC 4)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to dynamically create hidden fields for a set of properties, but I'm getting a 500 server error when I submit the form. I confirmed the following:

- The properties I'm iterating over in the foreach statement are correct.
- property.Name is a valid property name for the type retrieved by NewItem.GetType()

Here's what I have:

**View**

```
@model PaneViewModel

using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddItem", "Action", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "tool-wrapper",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
}))
{
    // Some standard input fields here (these are working properly).

    [...]

    // Here's what's broken:
    @foreach (var property in Model.NewItem.GetType().GetProperties().Where(<criteria here>))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewItem.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name), column.GetValue(Model.NewItem, null))
    }

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
}
```

**ItemViewModel**

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int SomeField { get; set; }
    public int AnotherField { get; set; }
}
```

**PaneViewModel**

```
public class PaneViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel NewItem { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItem([Bind(Prefix = "NewItem")] ItemViewModel model)
{
    // Stuff here.
}
```

It's worth noting that the following generates the hidden fields with the correct names and values in the generated HTML, but the values of the hidden field aren't posted to the controller action:

```
@foreach (var property in Model.NewItem.GetType().GetProperties().Where(<criteria here>))
{
    @Html.Hidden(property.Name, column.GetValue(Model.NewItem, null))
}
```

So it seems the problem is with the `m => m.NewItem.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name)` component

Comment: `@Html.Hidden(property.Name, ..` would not _"generate the hidden fields with the correct names"_ since it would generate `name="SomeField"` not `name="NewItem.SomeField"` (which is why it wont bind). What are you actually trying to do (this sort of logic does not belong in a view)

Comment: Just seen your edit where you have added `[Bind(Prefix = "NewItem")]`, but in any case what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I have a handful of ViewModels that I want to have use the same View (the goal of this project is having the ability to add more ViewModels and not having to create a View for each one). So rather than having a View for every model that looks like

`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Field1)
[...] // More fields

@Html.HiddenFor(m => Field8)
[...] // More hidden fields`

I want to be able to define which fields in the model should be in hidden fields, and which ones should have editors display in the UI (that's what the Where() achieves), and have the single generic View display those models.

Comment: `.GetProperty()` returns typeof [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) so I don't see how you could make it work in `HiddenFor()` which expects `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`. In any case, why not just add the `[HiddenInput]` attribute to the properties, and use `@Html.EditorForModel()`

Comment: If I use `@Html.EditorForModel()`, then I lose the ability to lay out the UI the way I want to. I can specify an editor template, but then I'd have to either write a separate editor template for each ViewModel, or try to do what I'm doing now with the dynamic View.

Comment: A view is not the place for this type of logic. Create you own html helper where you pass the model and the criteria (or check for the existence of the `HiddenInputAttribute`), and generate the html for the hidden inputs. But you should not be rendering a lot of hidden inputs in any case - any one can change their value and it just degrades performance - you should be using view model with just the properties you need to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This type of logic does not belong in a view
2. `Html.HiddenFor()` expects an expression (`Expression<Func<TModel,
   TProperty>>`) as the first parameter, but `.GetProperty()` returns
   typeof `PropertyInfo`
3. You should not be generating multiple hidden inputs for properties
   of your model, but rather use a view model to represent only what
   you need to edit (it degrades performance by sending extra data to
   the client and then posting it back again unchanged, and anyone
   could use FireBug or similar tools to change the values and you
   might be none the wiser.

However, if you do want to do this, the you could create a html helper that generates hidden inputs for all properties marked with the `[HiddenInput]` attribute (or modify this example to pass in some condition that filters the required properties)

```
public static MvcHtmlString HiddenForModel<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
  StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
  ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
  var properties = metaData.Properties.Where(p => p.TemplateHint == "HiddenInput");
  foreach(var property in properties)
  {
    html.Append(helper.Hidden(property.PropertyName));
  }
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
}
```

Note this will also generate the `id` and `data-val-*` attributes which are probably unnecessary, so you could minimize the generated html by using

```
foreach(var property in properties)
{
  TagBuilder input = new TagBuilder("input");
  input.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input.MergeAttribute("name", property.PropertyName);
  input.MergeAttribute("value", string.Format("{0}", property.Model));
  html.Append(input.ToString());
}
```